# Uploading a file to Sharepoint 2013 (Skydrive Pro) using a C# desktop app

Tags: development, 2013, rest

I am trying to write a C# desktop app (a simple console application for now) using which I can upload a file to our Skydrive Pro instance (which is accessible using the same API's as that of SharePoint) using a REST api

I have tried a number of solutions, too many to start listing here, but given the number of roadblocks I am facing, my guess is that I am doing something fundamentally wrong.

One of the methods I used was: http://blog.cloudshare.com/2012/12/16/access-and-manipulate-data-in-your-cloudshare-sharepoint-2013-farm-from-anywhere-with-csom-rest-and-odata/  which fails in the GetFormDigest function, specifically in

```
        HttpWebResponse responsePost = (HttpWebResponse)requestPost.GetResponse();
```

giving a HTTP 500 error. Looking at the error in Fiddler, it says there is an authentication issue even though I am able to see some authentication data being passed in the request, the code I used for authentication was:

```
        requestPost.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        requestPost.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        requestPost.Method = "POST";
        requestPost.ContentLength = 0;
```

Any advice\tutorials\walkthroughs would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In the code example that you mentioned, the author did't use default credentials, he specified a login name and password.  Like this:

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;

// Obtain these values from your environment's home page
context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
```

If you aren't providing login credentials, I would expect the server to think you were some anonymous user, and reject you.